# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'rus.id' in 'on clause'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Espero y me puedan ayudar es que no me funciona la consulta que necesito hacer este es el código:

```
select permisos_roles_usuarios.*,   IF(rus.id is null, false, true) as rutas_permitidas
    FROM bloques_rutas_sistema
    left join permisos_roles_usuarios on permisos_roles_usuarios.id_ruta =rus.id
    left join rutas_sistema as rus on rus.id_bloque = bloques_rutas_sistema.id
    where bloques_rutas_sistema.id = 5;
```

Me manda el error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'rus.id' in 'on clause'

Espero y me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Cual es el objetivo que buscas con este codigo?

Comment: el objetivo es crear un boton donde el usuario pueda activar la ruta o desactivar la ruta, por eso es esta consulta

Comment: El mensaje de error es bastante claro: no existe una columna llamada  `id`  en la tabla `rutas_sistema`.

Comment: left join permisos_roles_usuarios on permisos_roles_usuarios.id_ruta =rus.id; ahí es donde tienes el problema, no estas agregando referencia de la tabla rus antes de llamarla